# ZF2 - validation within a bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework2

I am using twitter bootstrap in a zf2 application. A bootstrap modal displays a form containing user details, which i would like to be edited and saved. This is fairly trivial if i just submit form in the dialog and reload the whole page, but i am looking for a way to validate the form without it being submitted, and ideally if the data is valid, for it to pass the new data back to the page when the modal dialog is closed.

How can i do this - would it need to be an ajax call? If so how would i structure that in my controller to return the form validation in a way that the errors can be rendered in the modal?

Edit 1:
Accepted answer below is spot on so far.

The only thing i'm having trouble understanding is how to pass the validation data from the controller back to the bootstrap modal.

So as a simple workflow - modal window opens loaded with an edit form bound to a User model, which shows the User data to be edited (all preloaded and assigned to the view already). The modal form is submitted, jquery hooks onto the form submit and sends the data as an ajax request to UserController::EditUserAction - where the form data is validated against the models inputfilter. If it turns out to be valid, the data is saved and the modal dialog is closed. If the data is invalid, say changing the email address to an address that already exists, the action returns a JsonModel with the form error(s) - how is this then passed to the bootstrap modal to highlight the field that produced the error, like the way that ZF does automatically when a form is typically submitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do this with ajax.  To understand what to do in your controller you have to understand the fundementals of an ajax call.  jQuery makes this pretty easy.

```
<script>
$(function() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: method,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // Do something to handle the error
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      // Do something else on successful validation
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

The `type` is the HTTP method (eg. `'POST'`).
The `url` is the the route to get you to the controller which will give you a response.
The `data` is the form data to be sent.
More documentation is at https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

The success function is executed if the HTTP response code is in the 200's.
If you send an HTTP response code in the 400's or 500's, the javascript in the error function will be executed.  This can be used to show an error in your modal dialog.

You can modify the HTTP response code in a controller by using the following code:

```
$this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(400);
```

where 400 is the HTTP response code (see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html for more info about HTTP response codes)

Then, to send data back with the response, return a `JsonModel` in the controller instead of a `ViewModel`

```
return new JsonModel($array);
```

where `$array` is the data you want to send back to the browser.

If you end up doing this a lot, you might investigate the zf2 class \Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController.

Comment: So in my controller i get the bound object from the form, validate the post data against the objects inputfilter - then how would i return and populate errors / messages back to the bootstrap modal, without it closing?

Comment: @John, feel free to add a code snippet or two.  I don't know if you're asking about how to do this from the controller (zf2) or in the browser with javascript.  However, since you probably already followed my direction, you may have successfully sent an error/message from the controller to the browser.  In this case, you may simply need to simply remove the `data-dismiss="modal"` attribute from the `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>` in the modal dialog box to ensure that clicking the button does not close the modal dialog.

Comment: Great help so far, i've added a bit more info about where i'm stuck

Comment: John, if I could get a little more information, it would be helpful.  Specifically, if I could see some code at the end of your controller and/or if I could see the http response, that would be awesome.  You can get the http response by opening the Chrome Dev Tools, clicking the Network tab, clicking the make of the ajax request, and then clicking the "Response" tab.  Of course, to see this information, the page must not refresh after the response is received by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

if you want try for validation before submit form (send data to server) . may be better use client side validation .

http://www.rayfaddis.com/blog/2013/05/27/jquery-validation-with-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: Thanks, but i don't really want to duplicate all my validation rules - they are already defined in my model code, which i would like to use, i'm just unsure how to return the validation information from the controller back to the bootstrap modal.