# Validating a form dynamically within a bootstrap modal using both php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, twig, bootstrap-modal

I initially was relying on a page refresh which then displayed any errors (if required fields were not met) on my address add/edit form based on a validating function from within a php controller file. I then adapted my form to use a bootstrap modal instead with a dynamically loaded form which I got to work fantastically for submitting the data. However, the one slight issue I have is that while a back-end validation will prevent the updated/added data from actually submitting the form, it doesn't display a client-side validation error which in turn will prevent the modal from closing and not appear to submit anything. I looked at this link: [ZF2 - validation within a bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418104/zf2-validation-within-a-bootstrap-modal) but it doesn't seem to suit my needs. I really would like to avoid using jquery to **entirely** validate my form on the client-side somehow. I just need to use jquery with an ajax call to somehow check against my existing php controller file and show any errors directly in my modal while also preventing the form submitting if such errors are found.

Pertinent code from my php file:

```
public function getAddressForm() {
    $this->load->language('customer/customer');

    if (isset($this->request->get['customer_id'])) {
        $customer_id = $this->request->get['customer_id'];
    } else {
        $customer_id = 0;
    }   

    $this->load->model('customer/customer');

    $data['text_address'] = !isset($customer_id, $this->request->get['address_id']) ? $this->language->get('text_address_add') : $this->language->get('text_address_edit');

    if (isset($this->error['firstname'])) {
        $data['error_firstname'] = $this->error['firstname'];
    } else {
        $data['error_firstname'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['lastname'])) {
        $data['error_lastname'] = $this->error['lastname'];
    } else {
        $data['error_lastname'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['address_1'])) {
        $data['error_address_1'] = $this->error['address_1'];
    } else {
        $data['error_address_1'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['city'])) {
        $data['error_city'] = $this->error['city'];
    } else {
        $data['error_city'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['postcode'])) {
        $data['error_postcode'] = $this->error['postcode'];
    } else {
        $data['error_postcode'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['country'])) {
        $data['error_country'] = $this->error['country'];
    } else {
        $data['error_country'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['zone'])) {
        $data['error_zone'] = $this->error['zone'];
    } else {
        $data['error_zone'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['custom_field'])) {
        $data['error_custom_field'] = $this->error['custom_field'];
    } else {
        $data['error_custom_field'] = array();
    }

    if (!isset($this->request->get['address_id'])) {
        $data['address_action'] = $this->url->link('customer/customer/addaddress', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'] . '&customer_id=' . $customer_id , true);
    } else {
        $data['address_action'] = $this->url->link('customer/customer/editaddress', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'] . '&customer_id=' . $customer_id . '&address_id=' . $this->request->get['address_id'], true);
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['address_id']) && ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')) {
        $address_info = $this->model_customer_customer->getAddress2($customer_id, $this->request->get['address_id']);
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['firstname'])) {
        $data['firstname'] = $this->request->post['firstname'];
    } elseif (!empty($address_info)) {
        $data['firstname'] = $address_info['firstname'];
    } else {
        $data['firstname'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['lastname'])) {
        $data['lastname'] = $this->request->post['lastname'];
    } elseif (!empty($address_info)) {
        $data['lastname'] = $address_info['lastname'];
    } else {
        $data['lastname'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['company'])) {
        $data['company'] = $this->request->post['company'];
    } elseif (!empty($address_info)) {
        $data['company'] = $address_info['company'];
    } else {
        $data['company'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['address_1'])) {
        $data['address_1'] = $this->request->post['address_1'];
    } elseif (!empty($address_info)) {
        $data['address_1'] = $address_info['address_1'];
    } else {
        $data['address_1'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['address_2'])) {
        $data['address_2'] = $this->request->post['address_2'];
    } elseif (!empty($address_info)) {
        $data['address_2'] = $address_info['address_2'];
    } else {
        $data['address_2'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['postcode'])) {
        $data['postcode'] = $this->request->post['postcode'];
    } elseif (!empty($address_info)) {
        $data['postcode'] = $address_info['postcode'];
    } else {
        $data['postcode'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['city'])) {
        $data['city'] = $this->request->post['city'];
    } elseif (!empty($address_info)) {
        $data['city'] = $address_info['city'];
    } else {
        $data['city'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['country_id'])) {
        $data['country_id'] = (int)$this->request->post['country_id'];
    }  elseif (!empty($address_info)) {
        $data['country_id'] = $address_info['country_id'];
    } else {
        $data['country_id'] = $this->config->get('config_country_id');
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['zone_id'])) {
        $data['zone_id'] = (int)$this->request->post['zone_id'];
    }  elseif (!empty($address_info)) {
        $data['zone_id'] = $address_info['zone_id'];
    } else {
        $data['zone_id'] = '';
    }

    $this->load->model('localisation/country');

    $data['countries'] = $this->model_localisation_country->getCountries();

    if (isset($this->request->post['default'])) {
        $data['default'] = $this->request->post['default'];
    } elseif (isset($this->request->get['address_id'])) {
        $data['default'] = $this->request->get['address_id'];
    } else {
        $data['default'] = '';
    }

    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('customer/customer_address_form', $data));
}

public function addAddress() {
    $this->load->language('customer/customer');

    if (isset($this->request->get['customer_id'])) {
        $customer_id = $this->request->get['customer_id'];
    } else {
        $customer_id = 0;
    }   

    $this->load->model('customer/customer');

    if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validateAddressForm()) {
        $this->model_customer_customer->addAddress($this->request->get['customer_id'], $this->request->post);

    }

    $this->getAddressForm();        
}

public function editAddress() {

    $this->load->language('customer/customer');

    if (isset($this->request->get['customer_id'])) {
        $customer_id = $this->request->get['customer_id'];
    } else {
        $customer_id = 0;
    }   

    $this->load->model('customer/customer');

    if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validateAddressForm()) {
        $this->model_customer_customer->editAddress($this->request->get['customer_id'], $this->request->get['address_id'], $this->request->post);

    }

    $this->getAddressForm();
}

protected function validateAddressForm() {
    if ((utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['firstname'])) < 1) || (utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['firstname'])) > 32)) {
        $this->error['firstname'] = $this->language->get('error_firstname');
    }

    if ((utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['lastname'])) < 1) || (utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['lastname'])) > 32)) {
        $this->error['lastname'] = $this->language->get('error_lastname');
    }

    if ((utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['address_1'])) < 3) || (utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['address_1'])) > 128)) {
        $this->error['address_1'] = $this->language->get('error_address_1');
    }

    if ((utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['city'])) < 2) || (utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['city'])) > 128)) {
        $this->error['city'] = $this->language->get('error_city');
    }

    $this->load->model('localisation/country');

    $country_info = $this->model_localisation_country->getCountry($this->request->post['country_id']);

    if ($country_info && $country_info['postcode_required'] && (utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['postcode'])) < 2 || utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['postcode'])) > 10)) {
        $this->error['postcode'] = $this->language->get('error_postcode');
    }

    if ($this->request->post['country_id'] == '' || !is_numeric($this->request->post['country_id'])) {
        $this->error['country'] = $this->language->get('error_country');
    }

    if (!isset($this->request->post['zone_id']) || $this->request->post['zone_id'] == '' || !is_numeric($this->request->post['zone_id'])) {
        $this->error['zone'] = $this->language->get('error_zone');
    }

    return !$this->error;
}
```

Pertinent code on my twig file that makes the modal form work and submit data, but no way to show client-side validation:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function update_address(id){

    $('#updateAddressModal').modal();
    $('#updateAddressModal .modal-body').load('index.php?route=customer/customer/editaddress&user_token={{ user_token }}&customer_id={{ customer_id }}&address_id='+id, function(){
        $('#updateAddressModal #address_form').submit(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();

            var post_url = $(this).attr("action");
            var request_method = $(this).attr("method");
            var form_data = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
                url : post_url,
                type: request_method,
                data : form_data
            }).done(function(response){
                $('#updateAddressModal').modal('hide');
                $('#address').load('index.php?route=customer/customer/getaddresslist&user_token={{ user_token }}&customer_id={{ customer_id }}');

            });
        });

        $('#updateAddressModal select[name=\'country_id\']').trigger('change');
    });


}
//--></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function add_address(){
    $('#addAddressModal').modal();
    $('#addAddressModal .modal-body').load('index.php?route=customer/customer/addaddress&user_token={{ user_token }}&customer_id={{ customer_id }}', function(){
        $('#addAddressModal #address_form').submit(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();

            var post_url = $(this).attr("action");
            var request_method = $(this).attr("method");
            var form_data = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
                url : post_url,
                type: request_method,
                data : form_data
            }).done(function(response){
                $('#addAddressModal').modal('hide');
                $('#address').load('index.php?route=customer/customer/getaddresslist&user_token={{ user_token }}&customer_id={{ customer_id }}');

            });
        });

        $('#addAddressModal select[name=\'country_id\']').trigger('change');
    });
}
//--></script>
```

My "action" in the form of my modal is what dictates if the modal is adding or editing an existing address. I'm sure the answer lies somewhere with it to check for validation through an ajax call I guess(?), so this is where I am stumped.:

```
<form action="{{ address_action }}" id="address_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="input-company">{{ entry_company }}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" name="company" value="{{ company }}" placeholder="{{ entry_company }}" id="input-company" maxlength="32" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>    
      <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="input-firstname">{{ entry_firstname }}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" name="firstname" value="{{ firstname }}" placeholder="{{ entry_firstname }}" id="input-firstname" maxlength="16" class="form-control" />
          {% if error_firstname %}
          <div class="text-danger">{{ error_firstname }}</div>
          {% endif %}
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="input-lastname">{{ entry_lastname }}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" name="lastname" value="{{ lastname }}" placeholder="{{ entry_lastname }}" id="input-lastname" maxlength="16" class="form-control" />
          {% if error_lastname %}
          <div class="text-danger">{{ error_lastname }}</div>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="input-address-1">{{ entry_address_1 }}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" name="address_1" value="{{ address_1 }}" placeholder="{{ entry_address_1 }}" id="input-address-1" maxlength="32" class="form-control" />
          {% if error_address_1 %}
          <div class="text-danger">{{ error_address_1 }}</div>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="input-address-2">{{ entry_address_2 }}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" name="address_2" value="{{ address_2 }}" placeholder="{{ entry_address_2 }}" id="input-address-2" maxlength="32" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="input-city">{{ entry_city }}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" name="city" value="{{ city }}" placeholder="{{ entry_city }}" id="input-city" maxlength="30" class="form-control" />
          {% if error_city %}
          <div class="text-danger">{{ error_city }}</div>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="input-zone">{{ entry_zone }}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <select name="zone_id" id="input-zone" class="form-control">
          </select>
          {% if error_zone %}
          <div class="text-danger">{{ error_zone }}</div>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="input-postcode">{{ entry_postcode }}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" name="postcode" value="{{ postcode }}" placeholder="{{ entry_postcode }}" id="input-postcode" class="form-control" />
          {% if error_postcode %}
          <div class="text-danger">{{ error_postcode }}</div>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="input-country">{{ entry_country }}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <select name="country_id" id="input-country" onchange="country(this, '{{ zone_id }}');" class="form-control">
            <option value="">{{ text_select }}</option>
              {% for country in countries %}
              {% if country.country_id == country_id %}
              <option value="{{ country.country_id }}" selected="selected">{{ country.name }}</option>
              {% else %}
              <option value="{{ country.country_id }}">{{ country.name }}</option>
              {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
          </select>
          {% if error_country %}
          <div class="text-danger">{{ error_country }}</div>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">{{ entry_default }}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          {% if default %}
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="default" value="1" checked="checked" />
            {{ text_yes }}</label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="default" value="0" />
            {{ text_no }}</label>
          {% else %}
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="default" value="1" />
            {{ text_yes }}</label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="default" value="0" checked="checked" />
            {{ text_no }}</label>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="text-center" style="padding:12px;"><button id="save-address" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Address</button></div>
</form>
```

I am suspecting that I may need to use json in all of this to display the errors, but I am unsure. I'm using jquery 2.1.1 for this particular project of mine as well as bootstrap 3.3.0, but I can adapt **any** answers thrown at me for it if someone can point me in my the right direction.

**UPDATE:** I marked the correct answer below which helped me tremendously. To include what I did with the answer, I encased my errors in empty divs and simply used .html to populate them with any errors found.

Example:

```
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="input-postcode">{{ entry_postcode }}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="postcode" value="{{ postcode }}" placeholder="{{ entry_postcode }}" id="input-postcode" class="form-control" />
      {% if error_postcode %}
      <div class="text-danger">{{ error_postcode }}</div>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Was changed to:

```
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="input-postcode">{{ entry_postcode }}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="postcode" value="{{ postcode }}" placeholder="{{ entry_postcode }}" id="input-postcode" class="form-control" />
      <div id="error-postcode"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And then, all I needed to do was keep adding my .html for all the error divs I needed to populate with any errorssimilar as follows:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: post_url,
            type: request_method,
            data: form_data
        }).done(function(response){
           if(!response.success) {
                //Dont close the modal, display the error
                $('#error-postcode').html('{% if error_postcode %}<div class="text-danger">{{ error_postcode }}</div>{% endif %}');
            }
            else {
                $('#addAddressModal').modal('hide'); 
                $('#address').load('index.php?route=customer/customer/getaddresslist&user_token={{ user_token }}&customer_id={{ customer_id }}');
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Send a JSON response from the server to the client. You can specify whether the validation was successful or not, send the reason alongside etc

In the backend, if you are using, say Symphony, you can send the response like this:

```
return new JsonResponse(array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Invalid EMail'));
```

So, the client side code becomes something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url : post_url,
                type: request_method,
                data : form_data
    }).done(function(response){

        if(!response.success) {
            //Dont close the modal, display the error
            $('#err').html(response.message);
        }
        else {
            $('#addAddressModal').modal('hide'); 
            $('#address').load('index.php?route=customer/customer/getaddresslist&user_token={{ user_token }}&customer_id={{ customer_id 
        }
    });
});
```

You can almost avoid the error display sections of the template handled by PHP. Let the frontend handle the display of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your ajax call code..

```
$.ajax({  
    type: request_method,  
    url:  "post_url",  
    data: form_data,  
    cache: false,  
    success: function(result){  
        if(result===1){  
            // On success redirect...return 1 from backend if no errors are there.  
         $('#addAddressModal').modal('hide');  
        }  
        else  
            //display error message..create response 'result' in backend such that you can display all errors
            //for eg : foreach error append a number to response and in client side use js include to check if certain error is there or not.
    }  
    });
```

---

Answer (score 0):

**It works 100 %.**

javaScript File:

```
// add receipt data
            $('#insert_form').on("submit", function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "includes/user-insert.inc.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: $('#insert_form').serialize(),
                    async: true,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $('#insert').val("Inserting");
                    },
                    success: function(data) {

                        $('#insert_form')[0].reset();
                        $('#add_reciept').modal('hide');
                        //$('#receipt-table').html(data);
                        dataTable.ajax.reload(null, false);

                        //$('#alert-success').show();

                        if (data == "No") {
                            $('#alert-danger').addClass('alert alert-danger');
                            $('#alert-danger').html('<strong>Oh snap!</strong> Sorry, that Record wasn\'t Added <b>Try Again</b>');
                            $('#alert-danger').fadeIn().show();
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                $('#alert-danger').fadeOut("slow");
                            }, 8000);
                        } else if (data == "Yes") {
                            $('#alert-success').html('<strong>Well done!</strong> A Record has been Added.');
                            $('#alert-success').addClass('alert alert-info');
                            $('#alert-success').fadeIn().show();
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                $('#alert-success').fadeOut("slow");
                            }, 8000);
                        }


                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                        $('#alert-danger').addClass('alert alert-danger');
                        $('#alert-danger').html('<strong>Oh snap!</strong> Sorry, that Record wasn\'t Added <b>Try Again</b>');
                        $('#alert-danger').fadeIn().show();
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $('#alert-danger').fadeOut("slow");
                        }, 8000);
                    },
                    complete: function(data) {
                        $('#insert').val("Insert");
                    }
                });

            });
```

Process.inc.php file:

```
// check users again or not
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM users_acc WHERE U_Email='$U_Email'";
          $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
          $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

          if ($resultCheck > 0) {
            //header("Location: ../users-control?signup=usertaken");
            //exit();
            /* $output .= '<div style="margin-top:1rem;" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                            <strong>Oh snap!</strong> Sorry, that Record wasn\'t updated <b>Try Again</b>  
                            </div>'; */
            //$output['status'] = false;

            echo 'No';
          } else {

            $query = "
                INSERT INTO users_acc(Firstname, Lastname, U_Email, U_Password, Gender, user_role_id)  
                 VALUES('$Firstname', '$Lastname', '$U_Email', '$U_Password', '$Gender' , '$user_role_id')
                ";
            //$output['status'] = true;
            echo 'Yes';
        }
```